# Are there official, complete statistics for these exotic weapons?

Tags: weapons, dnd-3e, miniatures

The Wizards of the Coast Web site hosts [Battle Sheets!](http://archive.wizards.com/dnd/article.asp?x=minis/ch20020924bs) that convert figures from the [*Chainmail Miniatures Game*](https://www.amazon.ca/Dungeons-Dragons-Chainmail-Miniatures-Starter/dp/0743004450) into *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition*. Some of these Battle Sheets have dwarves armed with exotic weapons:

- The dwarf lightning lancer and the lightning lance.
- The dwarf shock trooper and the gun.
- The dwarf scorcher and the fire bomb.
- The dwarf thunderlasher and the thunderlash.

While *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* has a *lightning lance* (*Lords of Madness* 115), the *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition* grell (*Monster Manual II* 121-2) doesn't include in its description a *lightning lance*. This makes all of these weapons, so far as I know, unique to the Battle Sheets—even the gun, the *Dungeon Master's Guide* instead using Exotic Weapon Proficiency (firearms) for such weapons.

#### Were official and complete *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition* statistics for these weapons—including, for example, price and weight—made available?

Comment: Gah! I'm going to go ahead and clean up my idle-curiosity comments, but one actual on-topic one: Is the [tag:miniatures] tag really appropriate here? I can see how it's related, but going off how it's used the [tag:chainmail]  tag might make more sense. Interesting sidenote: No-one's ever asked a question about Chainmail before.

Comment: @Miniman I figured folks who were familiar with the miniatures would have access to material I didn't, and I didn't want to anger OSR folks by tagging a question *Chainmail* only to have them realize I was curious about the modern miniatures game rather than the *D&D* precursor. But if you disagree, I'm not married to the tags.

Comment: @Miniman The chances of a question on Chainmail, since it is a table top miniatures game rather than an RPG, is pretty small.   I have referenced Chainmail in a few answers, to include the simple jousting rules for a TTRPG jousting question, but I think that if someone did ask a Chainmail question it would likely get closed as off-topic at RPG.SE.

Comment: I expect that it's extremely unlikely that an Official source will be found. D&D has traditionally been a rather DIY system, where if you don't have a rule, you make a ruling. *Optimizers* don't use that idea much, because we feel the need to point to rules whenever possible, in order to 'defend' a build. I expect that WotC left the complete stats 'as an exercise for the student.'

Comment: @Chemus While I agree generally, I think a distinction can be made here: These battle sheets are presented as complete, ready-to-use products yet, upon closer examination, they aren't really usable as-is. That is, for example, it's not like the sheets say *This dwarf has a gun; make up stats yourself* (which I'd be totally okay with), but, instead, the dwarf shock trooper *seems* good to go *then* falls apart (its gun lacks a range increment, for instance). Rather than level accusations of deception or incompetence, I want it to be me who has overlooked something.

Comment: The "Note: Battle Sheets are created with an eye toward utility in combat. They do not include some statistics (found in standard monster or character sheets) that do not pertain to battle situations..." from the front page of the link suggests that it's an unintentional oversight. Looking over the sheets for myself now...

Comment: None of the other sheets explain anything regarding the equipment either; these items appear to be either extrapolated from the minis' visible equipment, and the author got carried away on the dwarves, or they're from the original Chainmail game (of which I don't think I have any data)

Comment: O, I know! Hence the question. `:-)` (Despite a multitude of questions, I really do tend to perform a fair amount of research before I post one. Honest!) Like I said a few comments up, I was hoping a *Chainmail* fan might've stumbled across the full stats somewhere. Thank you, though, for a second set of eyes on the issue. I appreciate it.

Comment: Having researched the issue, the only available rules not presented are weapon ranges, in inches. This should convert to 5' increments in D&D. Weight, price, loading, and construction are not part of the chainmail rules. The ranges are on the individual model's Datacard, which is provided in its packaging, whether individual or as a boxed set. As Chainmail was discontinued in 2002, the rulebook is hard to obtain, and the datacards seem to be only in hardcopy as far as I can tell. Said rulebook contains a few sample datacards, but none of those you're requesting info on. I can't find the cards.

Comment: @Chemus An answer that documents your research that's preceded by a fairly confident *No* might be worth posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No

The complete statistics for those weapons were never presented publicly. Each creature in the Chainmail game had a Stat Card that was included with the miniature. The card documented the combat statistics of the creature, including even more abstracted Health and Damage scores, plus movement rates and ranged weapon ranges in inches, but did not include price, weight, etc.

The Chainmail game was discontinued in 2002, and the stat cards were not distributed digitally, except those for unreleased models (last few models of [set 4](http://archive.wizards.com/dnd/article.asp?x=minis/ch20021029sc), all of [set 5](http://archive.wizards.com/dnd/article.asp?x=minis/ch20021105x)). The successor, D&D Miniatures, had [digitally released stat cards](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/mi/20090430) and rules for using *some* of the minis from Chainmail within the D&D Minis' League play.

None of the 4 model you're interested in are included in the [League sanctioned list](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/mi/20031127a), and even they were removed in later League lists. The successor to League D&D Minis is [D&D Mini's Guild](https://box1055.bluehost.com/%7Eddmguil1/), whose [original](https://box1055.bluehost.com/%7Eddmguil1/?q=dd-miniatures-original-edition-rules-and-cards) and [revised](https://box1055.bluehost.com/%7Eddmguil1/?q=rules-and-cards) cards don't appear to include those 4 cards. If you want a Stat card, you appear to need to purchase a complete mini or Mordengard set 3 or 4 boxed set. They're hard to find.

### Finding Rules

The Chainmail Core Rulebook, which was released for sale as a digital download after the game was discontinued, has a section on p.117 that says

> ... All Chainmail models have D&D statistics, and almost all of them have their statistics published in guidebooks, in Dragon® Magazine, and on the Wizards of the Coast® website...[which] has “battle sheets” for many Chainmail models. Each one-page sheet gives you all the information you need to run a Chainmail model as a D&D monster or NPC...
>
> If you want to use a Chainmail model in a D&D game and don’t have a battle sheet for it, you can use a quick-and-dirty system to convert its health and damage scores to D&D statistics. For each point of the model’s health, roll 2d4 for hit points, and for each point of damage (melee or ranged), roll 1d10. If you’re feeling industrious, you can also adjust some of the creature’s saving throws up and others down instead of using the single save number.

The rest of the section details movement rates, and D&D 3.0 rules for the space of Large (Tall) or Large (Long) creatures, then goes into using the Chainmail rules for command and morale.

The next section on pp.118-122 discusses converting D&D creatures and characters for use within the Chainmail rules, and the only thing it says about weapon ranges is

> For thrown weapons, give the model a 6˝ range. For projectile weapons, give the model a 24˝ range. Give a model with a ranged weapon either a one-shot limit or no limit on the number of ranged attacks it may make. (Keeping track of ammunition is a hassle, but remembering whether a model has
> used its single ranged attack is easy.)

These rules *might* extrapolate in reverse, but the Battle Sheets presented don't detail such.

Dragon #291, which has a section on Chainmail's Mordengard dwarves, has no details to offer regarding the stats of these minis.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The question requested price, weight, etc., be included among the stats. They were never publicly presented, for free or otherwise. The only stat that was released publicly for a fee, rather than being in the free Battle Sheets, was that of range, and even that I could not find.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the sentences, and they seemed to contradict each other. I added your note to the end of the sentence where the logical thread seemed to get lost, so it's reinforced instead.

Comment: Thanks, @SevenSidedDie, Obviously that hadn't occurred to me.